# Retrieved data from parse.com but it is in HashCode

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to retrieve data from parse.com and show it in listview. but when i retrieve it and it shows me in hashcode. I have pasted picture of output.Please look into my query code and correct me. 
Here is code for pulling data from parse.com

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                for (ParseUser user : list) {
                    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();

                    newUser.getString(user.getString("username"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Latitude"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Longitude"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Bloodtype"));
                    newUser.getString(user.getString("Mobile"));
                    user1.add(newUser);

                }
                ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,user1);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: why are you creating an empty ParseUser object and then getting the value using the value of the received values as key?

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it. I need to work on my java basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter just use the toString of each object in the array.
Every user that you add to list is displayed as a pointer, this is the to string method of the ParseUser object.

If you are trying to display all information about the user you should create a custom adapter and implement the getView method.
If you want to check for now if it works correctly you can pass a list of just username for example and check if it works, then you can move on and implement your own adapter.

**Edit:**
For creating custom adapter check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: How should i check it? any example code? and i have not idea how to make custom adapter

Comment: I edited my answer, check this link for creating a custom adapter with a custom layout, the adapter you are trying to use is to for displaying only one string in a row.

Comment: Ok if i use custom adapter then i don't need to use ListFragment?  I am sorry for asking dumb questions. I am new into android

Comment: ListFragment is a fragment with embedded list. You still need to use ListFragment but instead of using ArrayAdapter in your code you should instantiate you own custom adapter.

Comment: Thanks. I will learn custom adapter now then i will implement it in my Fragment which extends ListAFragment

Comment: Thanks much. I followed as you told. It is working now